# PHP+MySQL UPDATE query (multiple columns) not working

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, it's probably something simple that I'm overlooking, but I've combed through this so many times..!

Just a simple update via a PHP form, pulls in variables, builds query:

```
// Connect
$connect = mysql_connect('host','login','passwd');
if (!$connect) { $errors .= "Not connected : ".mysql_error(); }
$database = mysql_select_db('db', $connect);
if (!$database) { $errors .= "Could not get to that database: ".mysql_error(); }

// Update database table
$info = "UPDATE `gsa_officers` SET `term` = '2012-2013', `office` = 'President', `type` = 'Poop', `dept` = 'Visual Arts', `name` = 'Matthew W. Jarvis', `email` = 'president@gsa.ucsd.edu', `blurb` = 'Serves as Chair of both the GSA Executive Committee and Council, oversees the direction of the organization and ensures the execution of its responsibilities and commitments.', `picture` = 'http://gsa.ucsd.edu/sites/gsa.ucsd.edu/files/mat%20w%20jarvis.jpg' WHERE `id` = 1";
$query = mysqli_query($info);
if (!$query) { $errors .= "Bad query: ".mysql_error(); }
mysql_close($connect);
```

I get no errors, it only prints out: "Bad query: "

What am I missing/doing wrong?
Any extra eyeballs are appreciated ^*_*^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `mysql_connect()` to connect to your database server and select the db.  Then you use `mysqli_query()` to run the query, then `mysql_error()` to report the error. You can't mix these API's.

You should use `mysqli_*` functions throughout, because the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from a future version of PHP.

Example:

```
// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','login','passwd','db');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) { $errors .= "Not connected : ".$mysqli->connect_error; }

// Update database table
$info = "UPDATE `gsa_officers` SET `term` = '2012-2013', `office` = 'President',
  `type` = 'Poop', `dept` = 'Visual Arts', `name` = 'Matthew W. Jarvis', 
  `email` = 'president@gsa.ucsd.edu', 
  `blurb` = 'Serves as Chair of both the GSA Executive Committee and Council, oversees the direction of the organization and ensures the execution of its responsibilities and commitments.',
  `picture` = 'http://gsa.ucsd.edu/sites/gsa.ucsd.edu/files/mat%20w%20jarvis.jpg' 
  WHERE `id` = 1";
if (!$mysqli->query($info)) {
    $errors .= "Bad query: ".$mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Lol, ok I'm an idiot. I had it all one way, it didn't work, so I replaced it with mysqli_* and it still didn't work, so I reverted it back to the original (or so I thought). Thanks, this works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$query = mysqli_query($info);
```

To

```
$query = mysql_query($info);
```

**NOTE**

```
mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
```

Comment: Damn, this is good to know! I just got back into mysql recently, after using Oracle SQL for a long time; I had no idea they were changing all the extensions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you connect using simple `mysql` (not `mysqli`) but use `mysqli_query` to send query

Answer (score 0):

What if you do mysql_query instead of mysqli_query?